# Ribbon Button Image Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon-button

I'm trying to load a image onto a Ribbon Button. This is the System.Windows.Controls.RibbonBar type.

here is the code I'm using

```
public RibbonGroup CreateButtons()
{
    RibbonGroup GroupControlComputers = new RibbonGroup();
    GroupControlComputers.Header = "Computer Control";

    GroupControlComputers.Items.Add(DropdownButton("DropDown Stuffs"));
    return GroupControlComputers;     
}

public RibbonButton DropdownButton(String Caption)
{
    RibbonButton NewRibbonButton = new RibbonButton();
    NewRibbonButton.Label = Caption;


    NewRibbonButton.AllowDrop = true;

    return NewRibbonButton;
}
```

I cant figure out how to add a icon. i can add the button without an image with no problems

Path to class file creating button is **MyProject\Functions\Ribbonbar.cs**
Path to the Icon File is **MyProject\Images\Test\smallicon.ico**

I have tried to figure out the LargeImageSource and just cant understand what I need to do.

Comment: How are you adding the image to your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two images which you need to specify: `LargeImageSource` and `SmallImageSource`, they actually need to be different (one - larger and one - smaller), but for test try this:

```
public RibbonButton DropdownButton(String Caption)
{
    RibbonButton NewRibbonButton = new RibbonButton();
    NewRibbonButton.Label = Caption;

    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.BeginInit();
    // your path to image might be different
    image.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Test/smallicon.ico"); 
    image.EndInit();

    NewRibbonButton.SmallImageSource = image;
    NewRibbonButton.LargeImageSource = image;

    NewRibbonButton.AllowDrop = true;

    return NewRibbonButton;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you. i dont think i would have figured that out on my own. If you have the time could you explain the ,,,/ portion of this string. thanks.

Comment: @NewBee see the PackUri documentation on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx